# Referencing to the current unidentified function in Lua

Tags: function, lua

I like using nested functions, but how can I deal with something like this:

```
addEvent("onQuestion", function() body end)
```

I want to do something like `removeEvent` in the same function, but it requires the function as a second argument

```
addEvent("onQuestion", function()
   do..some..stuff
   removeEvent("onQuestion", thisFunction)
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the way `removeEvent` identifies the specific event function to remove by providing that exact function, then that's what you have to do. So the function needs to be stored somewhere, so that the function can pass it to `removeEvent`.

That would typically look like this:

```
local function eventFunc()
   do..some..stuff
   removeEvent("onQuestion", eventFunc)
end

addEvent("onQuestion", eventFunc)
```

If you want a more generic solution, you can create an `addSelfRemoveEvent` wrapper function:

```
function addSelfRemoveEvent(eventName, func)
  local outer function()
    func()
    removeEvent(eventName, outer)
  end
  addEvent(eventName, outer)
end
```

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Fixed.